# awk to split variable length record and add unique number on each group of records

Tags: awk

i have a file which has variable length columns

```
x|y|XREC|DELIMITER|ab|cd|ef|IREC|DELIMITER|j|a|CREC|
p|q|IREC|DELIMITER|ww|xx|ZREC|
```

what i would like is

```
1|x|y|XREC|
1|ab|cd|ef|IREC|
1|j|a|CREC|
2|p|q|IREC|
2|ww|xx|ZREC|
```

So far i just managed to get seq number at the beginning

```
awk '{printf "%d|%s\n", NR, $0}' oldfile > with_seq.txt
```

Any help?

Comment: Clear input, output, and an attempted solution - +1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the delimiter to `DELIMITER`:

```
$ awk -F 'DELIMITER[|]' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print NR"|"$i}' file
1|x|y|XREC|
1|ab|cd|ef|IREC|
1|j|a|CREC|
2|p|q|IREC|
2|ww|xx|ZREC|
```

Comment: ditto. Remove the `*`.

Comment: Right. It was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk -F "DELIMITER" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print NR "|" $i}' file|sed 's/||/|/g'

1|x|y|XREC|
1|ab|cd|ef|IREC|
1|j|a|CREC|
2|p|q|IREC|
2|ww|xx|ZREC|
```

Comment: If you just wanted to get rid of a potential '|' at the start of each field, it's as easy to just do it inside the awk script as it is to add a pipe and a sed script: `{sub(/^\|/,"",$i); print NR "|" $i}'` and IMHO it makes it clearer what you're doing but YMMV I suppose.

Comment: I clean my comments, and accept your suggestions. Let's move on